# How can I set a variable to the output of an infinite loop in Posix shell script?

Tags: loops, sh, posix, infinite-loop

You can set a variable to a subshell's output like so in Bash, sh, etc.

```
$ var=$(echo "2")

$ echo $var
2
```

You can also set a variable to the output of a loop once it's completed.

```
$ i=0
$ var=$(while [ $i -ne 4 ]; do echo "$i"; i=$((i+1)); done)
$ echo "$var"
0
1
2
3
```

Is there anyway I can fork this loop, keep it running forever, and just get the latest version of the variable whenever it's referenced? I tried the following code but it gave no output.

```
$ i=0
$ var=$(while true; do echo "$i"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done) &
$ sleep 2
$ echo "$var"
```

I thought the variable was never set because the loop never finished. I would like for the output to be "3" here, and if I `echo "$var"` two seconds later, the output "5". As @user2864740 stated, the issue is related to the process being forked in the background. Is there a solution here, if I want the rest of my code to run while the infinite loop is running?

Comment: The question doesn't really relate to an infinite loop. It relates to updating a variable via a background job. (The conclusion reached in the question of why the variable was not set is also a bit suspect.)

Comment: A variable is not a queue. You define a string, *then* you assign that string as a value to a name.

Comment: Or do you literally want a variable whose value is incremented once per second, like `SECONDS` in `bash`?

Comment: @chepner Almost. I want a variable that is changed once per second (or other time unit), but I have a generic use case, so the variable needs to be changable to any string. Really I will call another function and make its output the new variable.

Comment: That's what you'll have to do; you can't implement your own self-updating variables in POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like for the output to be "3" here, and if I echo "$var" two seconds later, the output "5".

You cannot automatically assign a variable from inside a (sub)process. But you can access the most recent value from the loop using a temporary file that you overwrite with each iteration.

Of course you can save the value in a variable (`var=$(< file)`) or access the file directly (`cat file`).

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p); rm -f loopoutput' EXIT

i=0
while true; do echo "$i" > loopoutput; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done &
sleep 4
cat loopoutput
sleep 2
cat loopoutput
```

prints

```
3
5
```

The `trap` is only there to end the loop after the script finished and to delete the temporary file.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I can't do what I want in POSIX shell, so I migrated my code over to temporary files like this and it works now. I'll take that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you ask. You can, however, use a named pipe in place of the variable. One process can write to the pipe, the other can read from it.

```
mkfifo p

i=0
while :; do
  echo "$i"
  i=$((i+1))
  sleep 2
done > p &

while IFS= read -r num; do
  echo "$num"
  sleep 1
done < p
```

A named pipe effectively acts like a file, but one that has a fixed size. If the file is full, the writer will block until space is made by reading from it. Likewise, the reader will block if the pipe is empty until someone writes to it.

Comment: When I exit the program, the file 'p' stays. Can I make it disappear when the program is finished, particularly if I hit Ctrl + C since I'm dealing with infinite loops?

Comment: Put `trap 'rm -f p' EXIT` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I have a further concern. When run cat p, the cat command never finishes. I would like to grab what is currently in the pipe and then stop reading for a while, but I want the pipe to be updated anyway until the next time I read. From your description it sounds like the variable will not be updated unless it's actively being read, which I don't think is what I need.

Comment: @Socowi the trap command doesn't delete the file. I have to run rm -f p manually.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://onlinegdb.com/5qZtpef9_) your problem. For me, `p` is deleted each time I kill the script. Could it be that you are in an interactive shell and not in a script? In that case, when do you expect `p` to be deleted?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I ran your exact script on my system and I get this output. https://clbin.com/6wU96. I ran ./script

Comment: This is very strange. Sadly, I cannot help you with that as I cannot reproduce the problem and have no idea what could have gone wrong.

Comment: The purpose of `cat` is to read *all* its input and write it to standard output. It doesn't sound like you should be using `cat`, but rather read from the pipe more selectively.

Comment: @chepner I just don't know how to go about doing this. Your solution uses another while loop to input the pipe and I don't know how to adapt that to a non-loop, one-time run scenario.

Comment: I misunderstood your goal; what you want really is not possible in POSIX shell.